# Previous Schengen visa without interview, issued 5 years or 3 years ago?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

French Embassy in San Francisco states the following in the "Help" section:

> Application by mail is possible for short stay visas only, not for
>   long stays.
>
> If you already hold a short stay visa bearing the mention "VIS" on it
>   issued less than 5 years ago or a short stay visa issued by the French
>   Consulate after January 2017, you don’t have to apply in person (even
>   if this visa is expired, or if it is in an old passport). In that
>   case, you may apply by mail. Please mail us your completed application
>   form along with a copy of all the supporting documents as indicated by
>   France Visas.

However while applying for French short term visa the "previous Schengen visas" section asked "issued within previous **3 years**". So it is 5 or 3?

I was issued a Spanish Schengen visa in 2013 so that's within previous 5 years but not within previous 3. I did not know this 5 year thing so I applied for visa interview anyway. But if I need another short term visa soon, will my previous Spanish visa (or French visa if I get it this month) be considered?

Also, I do not remember if I was every fingerprinted for Spanish Schengen visa, so I selected "Not fingerprinted" in the application.

Comment: If your old visa includes the remark VIS, your biometrics should be on record. If not, probably no harm done by recording them again, except for the effort.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see a "VIS" on my previous visa so probably would have had to go for interview anyway.

Comment: If it was present, it would appear near the centre of the visa, as in [this example](https://www.thepoortraveler.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/French-Schengen-Visa.jpg).

Comment: @Giorgio Sorry, CHJ is asking explicitly what the exact terms are because there is conflicting information if it is 3 or 5 years. The "duplicate" does not clarify this question.